# Firebase | how to show information in php

Tags: php, json, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database

**Hello**
I have set a simple json db in firebase and i'm trying to show this on php page.

It's something like this?

```
<?php
// Constants
$FIREBASE = "https://pu***44.firebaseio.com";
$NODE_DELETE = "employee.json";
$NODE_GET = "employee.json";
$NODE_PATCH = ".json";
$NODE_PUT = "employee.json";
// Data for PUT
// Node replaced
$data = 32;
// Data for PATCH
// Matching nodes updated
$data = array(
    "employee" => 42
);
// JSON encoded
$json = json_encode( $data );
// Initialize cURL
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $FIREBASE . $NODE_PATCH );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
// Make request
// Close connection
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
// Show result
echo $response . "\n";
?>
```

Just making myself clear, i want it to show an item out of the json file. let say the first one.
Thanks!